# Setting ruler and hard wrap for Markdown and reStructuredText in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, markup

I'd like to configure PyCharm to set the ruler/visual guide to a slightly longer length (100 characters) and hard wrap at this point for text-based markup file types only (Markdown and reStructuredText) without affecting other languages. It seems like this should be possible but I can only see a way to set it globally in `Editor > Code Style`. It looks like you can override it in some of the nested settings pages for specific languages but Markdown and reStructuredText aren't listed.

Comment: PyCharm 2022.3.2 seems to have the `Editor -> Code Style -> Markdown -> Hard wrap at` setting, but no equivalent for reStructuredText. For e.g. HTML, JSON and XML I see `Hard wrap at: Default: 120` but I haven't yet found a way to change the default either.

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm 2022.3.2, you can now override the hard wrap column for Markdown
in `Editor` → `Code Style` → `Markdown` → `Hard wrap at:`.

There's no such setting for reStructuredText, so the best solution I've found is to set the default hard wrap column to 100 in `Editor` → `Code Style` → `Hard wrap at:` and configure shorter limits for other languages. Fortunately for the languages I work with most frequently it is possible to override it.